# Why Java produces an hour behind Casablanca real time?

Tags: java, time, timezone

While writing some experiments on the Java Data/Time API. I was wondering why this code doesn't function as expected:

```
ZonedDateTime CasaNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Casablanca"));
System.out.println(CasaNow);
// 2020-02-20T11:32:28.063419Z[Africa/Casablanca]
```

I was expecting it to print "2020-02-20T**12:32:28**.063419Z[Africa/Casablanca]" like in my clock.

This is the exact time in [Casablanca](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/timezone/africa--casablanca) but the program produces an hour behind that time. What am I doing wrong?

### Update

JDK Info:

```
java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Locale configuration of the operating system:

[image: locale configuration of the operating system]

Comment: The time showing on your clock... is it the same time showing on your computer's clock? When I run that code, I get `2020-02-20T12:41:32.546503+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]`, which is more like what you expect.

Comment: Yes, the time showing on my computer is the same as the time on my phone. But running the code doesn't produce the result you've mentioned. It produces exactly one hour behind that time

Comment: I run the code too and I obtained the result you expect.

Comment: Are you sure your computer's time zone is `Africa/Casablanca`? And haven't you changed the time zone to something else in your code?

Comment: Include full Java version info, as well as the locale configuration of your operating system.

Comment: Is your Java timezone database up to date?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm#JSTGD361

Comment: Btw I've run the snippet using multiple JREs. All of them produce the same result.

Comment: Stephen the docs say the issue could arise when using Windows. I am using macOS.

Comment: You shouldn't expect it to print 2020-02-20T12:32:28.063419Z - that Z would mean "UTC offset of 0" which would only be correct in 20 minutes. The correct output for a time zone 1 hour ahead of UTC would be 2020-02-20T12:41:32.546503+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]

Comment: I get `2020-02-20T13:14:30+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]` when running your code using JShell on JDK 13.0.1.

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is indeed the time zone database in your Java installation. The rules for Casablanca have changed quite a bit over the last two years.

Comment: I should mention that Casablanca is now on Daylight Saving Time. The gov added one hour.

Comment: Your link indicates Casablanca is currently using Standard Time, but will switch to DST on April 19.

Comment: Yes, the link is not correct. I live in Casablanca

Comment: I was expecting Java could figure out the Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: @hamzabelmellouki: Well it will if you've got the latest data. But it sounds like you *don't* have the latest data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, since 2018 Morocco is on UTC+01:00 except that is on offset +00:00 (often written as `Z`) during the month of Ramadan. So you are correct: getting a time in UTC (`Z`) today is unexpected since the Ramadan doesn’t begin until late April Gregorian.

According to BBC Morocco in October 2018 (1 year 4 months ago as of writing) decided to stay on its previous summer time (DST) also in winter. So my guess is that Stephen C is correct in the comment the time zone database in your Java installation is older than October 2018. Java therefore assumes standard time now and incorrectly gives you the time in UTC.

For what it‘s worth I just got `2020-02-20T19:08:47.375Z[Africa/Casablanca]` on Java 8 and `2020-02-20T20:06:43.174686+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]` on Java 11. So it seems that my Java 8 is from before October 2018 and my Java 11 is newer. As far as I remember none of them has had its time zone database updated after I installed them.

**Timezone Updater Tool**

Since you are using Oracle Java, the solution is to update Java’s time zone database using the Timezone Updater Tool. See the link at the bottom and follow the instructions given there. There have been a couple of Stack Overflow questions about that tool failing, though, so I hope that you will manage. The last resort would be to install a whole new Java runtime environment.

**Links**

- [Morocco abruptly drops clock change](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-45995634) on BBC 28 October 2018
- [Clock Changes in Casablanca, Morocco](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/morocco/casablanca) on timeanddate.com
- [Timezone Updater Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) on oracle.com

Answer (score 0):

Being from Morocco I noticed this issue too after our country's official time went back to UTC time for Ramadan. Even though Windows time has been updated, My application time wasn't, my logs and cronjobs were one hour in advance compared to current time, My JRE version was `1.8.0_202` which uses IANA version 2018g but this specification wasn't implemented until later versions of IANA, so to correct the timezone in JRE I downloaded the latest version of Java (JDK18) and copied two data files containing the time zone from their JDK18 to JRE8 locations:

Location of data files in JDK18:

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\lib\tzdb.dat`
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\lib\tzmappings`

Location of data files in JRE8:

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\tzdb.dat`
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\tzmappings`

By replacing the data files into your old JRE and restarting your application, the timezone gets fixed automatically. No need to use the tzupdater provided by Oracle.